# Python - An UDF to change the data types and replace values of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write an User defined function that sees the input column data type and changes it.

My Input data type will be either int64, float64, object, datetimens[64].

If it is a datetimens[64] then I am replacing the blank date with another custom date. The output data type will also be datetimens[64]

if it is an int64, float64 or object. I replace the blanks with "FILLINGTHENAS" - a string and convert all of these datatype to object.

```
def Change_Data_Type_DataFrame (AnyPandasDataFrame):
    cr_date = datetime(1800,1,1,1,1,1)        
    for i in range(1, AnyPandasDataFrame.shape[1]):
        Required_Column_Name = (AnyPandasDataFrame.columns[i])
        Required_Data_Type = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].dtype                                       
        if Required_Data_Type == 'datetime64[ns]':
            DateChecker = True
        else:
            DateChecker = contains_word(Required_Column_Name, "Date","of Death","Day of Work") 
        if DateChecker == False :
            if Required_Data_Type == 'int64':
                print("Yes")
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str)
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
            if Required_Data_Type == object:
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str)
                AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
            if Required_Data_Type == 'float64':
                    AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
                    AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str)
                    AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)         
        else:
            AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna(cr_date)
            AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype('datetime64[ns]')  
    return (AnyPandasDataFrame)
```

I have a huge dataframe of 100 columns and my function fails as I could see int64 in my output dataframe.

print - yes is not working, but my df surely has int64 dtypes.

Where am I going wrong, Can my code be better written.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to the code.

*Range was starting from 1, I made it to start from 0*

*I removed the multiple if's and made it as one single if logic*

*I re-set the data types after replacing again, just to make sure "Pandas was not setting it back".*

```
def Change_Data_Type_DataFrame (AnyPandasDataFrame):

cr_date = datetime(1800,1,1,1,1,1)        
for i in range(0, AnyPandasDataFrame.shape[1]):
    Required_Column_Name = (AnyPandasDataFrame.columns[i])
    print(Required_Column_Name)
    Required_Data_Type = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].dtype                                       
    if Required_Data_Type == 'datetime64[ns]':
        DateChecker = True
    else:
        DateChecker = contains_word(Required_Column_Name, "Date","of Death","Day of Work") 
    if DateChecker == False :
            AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna("FILLINGTHENAS")
            AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
            AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype(str)
    else:
        AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].fillna(cr_date)
        AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name] = AnyPandasDataFrame[Required_Column_Name].astype('datetime64[ns]')  
return (AnyPandasDataFrame)
```